# Get Key from php Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using `simplepie` to get some feeds, I have set the key in the array which I am having trouble accessing. Here's my code:

```
$feed->set_feed_url(array(
    'Title One'=>'http://example.com/rss/index.xml',
    'Title Two'=>'http://feeds.example.com/rss/example',
    'Title Three'=>'http://feeds.example.com/ex/blog'
));
```

When I loop over and try to access it I'm getting errors, here's how I am trying to access it.

```
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item):
echo $item[0];
```

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type SimplePie_Item as array

How can I access those I tried also:

```
echo $item->[0];
```

without luck.

Comment: Please do a `print_r($feed)` and post the output.

Comment: @JosephGarrone Output is very big, you can view it here http://pastebin.com/iG5tQuh9

Answer (score 1):

When you loop over an array (often used with associative arrays) using `foreach`, there is an additional construct to be able to get the key. It looks like this:

```
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $key => $item) {
   echo($key);
}
```

So an array with a structure like:

```
$myArray = [
   'a' => 1,
   'b' => 2,
];
```

When iterated with foreach in that syntax, will put "a" or "b" in the `$key` variable depending on which iteration it is, and `$item` will contain either "1" or "2".

In your case, `$item` is the object instance and then you are trying to access it like it is an array. If you need to know the key, use that other `foreach` syntax.

To get the title of the SimplePie_Item object, you can call `get_title()`:

```
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $index => $item) {
   echo($item->get_title());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in my case it's returning 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 etc and not the set key. Why's this?

Comment: What value are you expecting? "Title One"?

Comment: When you call `set_feed_url()` you are passing that data in, but that is not what `get_items` returns as a response. Looking briefly at the documentation, it looks like you need to call `$item->get_title()`

Comment: Yes you're right Jeremy, however there are feeds that don't supply titles, or have very long titles, which is causing issues at the moment. Anyway to access or set the title?

Comment: The full list of methods available for the `SimplePie_Item` class are at http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/start